# How to create Hugo multi level menu in the side nav from the front matter

Tags: hugo

I am new to Hugo, I am working on building a simple website, so I am trying to build multi-level menu in the left side which will work as a side nav in the website.

I am unable to find out how can we create multi level menu from front matter.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by mentioning the menu structure as array on front mater as how we give categories and sub cat, then the front mater will be available on page. But when in list page the data need to be assigned on _index.md under the list content folder